# Modifying all elements on a row after a delimiter in a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

If I have a 2d numpy (integers and d is also an integer) array like

```
[[0 1 2 d]
 [3 4 d 5]
 [6 d 7 8]]
```

How can I 0 all elements (row-wise) after d (and including) on each row?

I've used a for loop for this but I was wondering if there was a vectorised method via numpy. I've just seen that maybe you could subtract a triangular matrix :

```
[[0 0 0 d]
 [0 0 d 5]
 [0 d 7 8]]
```

but this doesn't solve my issue as it requires zeroing the values before d instead.

EDIT:

repr(array)

```
array([[0, 1, 2, d],
   [3, 4, d, 5],
   [6, d, 7, 8]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: What is `d`? Will it always be along a diagonal?

Comment: @jared just another integer and no not necessarily. I'll update the question. But if it was just the diagonal would it significantly change the solution?

Comment: can you print the `repr` of the array instead of the string (i.e. do `repr(arr)`)? makes the data much easier to work with

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I'll add that now just a sec.

Comment: how do you identify the position of `d`?

Comment: @mozway If I was doing it with a loop it would just be element-wise comparison. Once d is seen then zero the rest of the row.

Comment: @AnthonyML sorry your comment is unclear, can you provide a numerical example? Is `d` always on a diagonal? Can be seen elsewhere?

Comment: @mozway sorry. d only occurs once per line, and could be 0, -1, etc. But importantly it won't show up elsewhere in the array as it'd lead to more elements than necessary being zeroed. And no it's not always on the diagonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can craft a mask with [`cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and use it to mask the leading values with [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
d = 9
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, d],
              [3, 4, d, 5],
              [6, d, 7, 8]])

out = np.where(np.cumsum(a == d, axis=1), a, 0)
```

Variant with [`cumprod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html) and in place modification:

```
a[np.cumprod(a!=d, axis=1).astype(bool)] = 0
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 9],
       [0, 0, 9, 5],
       [0, 9, 7, 8]])
```

Intermediate masks (for the first approach, non-zero values are considered `True`):

```
# np.cumsum(a == d, axis=1)
array([[0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1]])

# np.cumprod(a!=d, axis=1).astype(bool)
array([[ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False]])
```